# Factory Model in C# and not using default constructor

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I've been using the factory model to create child forms to add to a MDI form. This is the code I've been using:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This uses the Factory Model to create the child node and then add it to the MDI Parent (this)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="childName">String class name of the child, i.e. RentalEase.PropertyGrid must extend Form or SingleInstance</param>
    /// <param name="singleInstance">bool If this class is to be a single instance and restricted to only on instance. Must extend SingleInstance</param>
    public void createChild(string childName, bool singleInstance) {
        if (singleInstance) {
            try {
                BaseAndSingleInstanceForm f = BaseAndSingleInstanceForm.getInstanceByType(this, Type.GetType(childName));
                    f.MdiParent = this;
                    f.Show();
                    f.BringToFront();
                    this.Refresh();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show("Could not create child: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        } else {
            try {
                object o = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(childName));
                if (o is Form) {
                    Form f = (Form)o;
                    f.MdiParent = this;
                    f.Show();
                    f.BringToFront();
                    this.Refresh();
                } else {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Class");
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show("Could not create child: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

However, a situation has arose that I have to add an integer parameter to the constructor of a specific form. How can I change this and make it reflect it while still maintaining the pattern at it's current ease of use (or nearly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a `Object[]` parameter to the method that would represent the parameters to the constructor of the object you wish to instantiate.  Then when you call `Activator.CreateInstance` you could pass that array in and `Activator` would do its best to find a constructor on the type you specified that matches the types in the `Object` array.

Here is a much simplified example of what I mean:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = (Foo)create("Foo", new Object[] { });
        Bar bar = (Bar)create("Bar", new Object[] { "hello bar" });
        Baz baz = (Baz)create("Baz", new Object[] { 2, "hello baz" });
    }

    static Object create(String typeName, Object[] parameters)
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(typeName), parameters);
    }   
}

class Foo
{
    public Foo() { }
}

class Bar
{
    public Bar(String param1) { }
}

class Baz
{
    public Baz(Int32 param1, String param2) { }
}
```

We have three types that all have different constructors - if the caller is responsible for sending in the type name then they will also be responsible for supplying an array of `Objects` that will satisfy a non-default constructor.